# Returning rows of marks in groups of 10s, 20s etc

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of seat numbers and marks like this:

```
seat    marks
61      45
62      25
63      45
64      23
65      25
66      9
67      23
```

The max mark is 100. Now I want to display how many candidates are securing marks in 10s, 20s, 30, .... 100s

```
marks     candidates_count
10        1
20        4
30        0
..        ..
```

And so on. 
Now I know this

```
SELECT seat, marks, count(marks) as counts from <table> group by marks order by counts  desc;
```

or do this for each 10s, 20s and 30s

```
SELECT seat, marks from <table> where marks>10 and marks<=20 group by marks;
```

and get the num of rows returned in my php and return the results, but thats not very elegant. There must be a way to do that directly in MySQL and without using MySQL for loops.

Comment: you should get `30 -> 4` instead of `20 -> 4`

Comment: Why should I get `30 -> 4`? there are four candidates securing marks in 20s i.e. seats numbers 62, 64, 65 & 67 securing 25, 23, 25 & 23 marks respectively.

Comment: @M Change:- If this is the case `9 (seat 66)` should come in `0's` and not in `10's`

Comment: @Salil Yes you are right. My bad sorry:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will definitely work for you

```
select (FLOOR(`marks`/ 10)+1)*10 as marks,
       count(*) as candidates_count
from <table>
group by (FLOOR(`marks`/ 10)+1)*10;
```

Comment: This worked out for me `SELECT floor(marks/10)*10 as tens, count(*) as No_of_canidates from <table> group by floor(marks/10)*10`
Dont know why are you using +1? for zero? +1 is giving me wrong incorrect rows as the marks are in 75.5 but its showing in 80s

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select (marks/10)*10 as marks,
       count(*) as candidates_count
from <table>
group by (marks/10)*10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select ((marks/10)+1)*10, count(1) 
from tab
group by ((marks/10)+1)*10
```

But if you want to see `0` you have to prepare expected marks:

```
create table tab2
(  
  marks int
)

insert into tab2 values(10)
insert into tab2 values(20)
insert into tab2 values(30)
insert into tab2 values(40)
insert into tab2 values(50)
insert into tab2 values(60)
....
insert into tab2 values(100)
```

and use `right join`:

```
select t2.marks, count(tab.marks) 
from tab
right join tab2 t2 on t2.marks = ((tab.marks/10)+1)*10
group by t2.marks
order by 1
```